# Angular Issue in updating local variable that is duplicated from global variable

Tags: angular, global-variables, local-variables

I have a global file where I store all global variables that need to be shared between different components in angular

```
export class GlobalContext {
    userData: any
    
    setUserData(user) {
        this.userData = user
    }
}
```

and in my component I assign it to a local variable as below

```
import {GlobalContext} from './globalContext.ts';

export class CreateEditComponent implements OnInit {
    favBook = [];
    constructor(private readonly gc: GlobalContext){}
    ngOnInit(): void {
        favBook = this.gc.userData.favBook;
    }
}
```

Here favBook is an array in both the global file and in the component.

Now when I use favBook in my component and push some data to it like below

```
this.favBook.push('Test 123');
```

The global data under userData.favBook is also getting updated. But here I am trying to update only the local variable inside the component. Only after the confirmation from the user I want to update the global variable.

What is the thing which I am missing and how can I duplicate the global data in my component. Please help

Comment: Make a clone of your array to assign to the local variable - `favBook = [...this.gc.userData.favBook]`

Answer (score 1):

As you assing the global value you create a shallow copy, which means that both `this.favBook` and `this.gc.userData.favBook` reference to the same memory address. You can read more info about this [here](https://medium.com/@manjuladube/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c).

If you want to have seperate values, you need to create a deep copy. In this case `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.gc.userData.favBook))` would probably do the trick. Or the spread operator with the array as it is written meanwhile in the comment by Sam.